My toilet has no working parts in the tank. I poured water into the bowl but it didn't work. Can it work without the tank?
My toilet has nothing in the tank. Can I flush it by pouring water in the bowl?

I don't think I want to ask how your toilet got into this condition.

it depends a lot on which type of toilet you have

Do you have a tank?  The insides of a toilet are inexpensive, so adding a water line and placing the parts in should not be that hard to have a working toilet.  No tank and it does get more expensive.

If you can keep a full 2-gallon bucket of water near the toilet...

Yes. The catch is that you have to get a lot of water in the bowl at one time. Consider that a typical toilet is now designed to flush with 1.6 gallons of water. The standard flush only takes a few seconds, so to get the same effect you have to pour ~ 1.6 gallons of water into the bowl in a few seconds. If you pour 1/2 gallon 3 times it will not flush as effectively as 1-1/2 gallons all at once.

This is one of the many uses of my 2 gallon general cleaning bucket. It has a nice wide pour spout, an easy to hold swinging handle, and a finger hold on the bottom opposite the spout to get a good grip for dumping it out. Makes it super easy to bucket flush a toilet!

I think people might get the wrong idea that an American-style toilet won't empty unless you put water in quickly. If your toilet is filled almost all the way to the top, and the siphon hasn't started, your toilet is clogged.

@JimmyJames It depends on how much water you put in how fast. It needs to be enough to actually form a seal across the outflow line to prime the siphon. And with a 3-inch drain on most toilets, that’s actually not a small amount of water. This isn’t some insane amount of water admittedly, but only pouring in a small glass of water at a time is usually not enough to do it. FWIW, the same is true for all Pythagorean siphons, the effect is just minimal with most other types because they usually have a narrow outflow line.

@AustinHemmelgarn  Yeah, I deleted my comment on your answer because I realized it was wrong.  Late on the coffee consumption today.  I realized a leaky toilet will not flush periodically.  I was thinking more about how sometimes a clogged toilet will spontaneously unclog and flush.  I just want to warn people not to pour a bucket of water into a very full bowl. It won't cause it to flush.

Probably yes, but it depends on the style of toilet and how much water you can get into it how quickly.
Most American-style flush toilets use a Pythagorean siphon (sometimes also known as a greedy cup siphon) to drain the bowl when flushing. This relies on getting enough water in the bowl quickly enough to actually prime the siphon effect, and because of how large the drain pipes have to be for it to actually work well as a toilet, ‘enough’ water is in fact quite a lot of water and ‘quickly enough’ is a matter of at most a dozen seconds. Even smaller, older toilets of this design need a significant percentage of a gallon, and some of the larger ones these days need 1.5 gallons of water or more. Not meeting that requirement will mean the toilet either does not flush effectively, or does not flush at all (and just drains slowly). For these toilets, you also need to ensure that you refill the bowl after each flush, both to enable the next flush (without filling the bowl, you will need much much more water to flush next time) and to ensure that you get an actual seal from the water in the bottom of the bowl to prevent sewer gas from entering the house.
In contrast, some European-style flush toilets, as well as all Asian-style squat toilets, simply use a large enough volume of flowing water to flush. These lack the siphon mechanism found in American-style flush toilets, and instead just rely on the water moving fast enough to drain everything away. These can also be flushed by just pouring water into the bowl, though it has to be poured in in the right place, and they still need enough water added fast enough to flush correctly.
Some toilets also rely on one or more water jets to clear the solid waste from the bowl. This aspect generally will not function if you just pour water into the bowl, though it usually just means that solid waste will not be cleared from the bowl quite as effectively.

Your "European-style" are often known as "washdown" toilets. IME the "fast enough" means you generally want to get the water in there very quickly - forget a dozen seconds, we're talking the whole flush finishing in about 3s. So while pouring water may work, you're also quite likely to have some ... residue.

Another method that might work is to use the tank.
You need to find something to permanently close the opening where the fill valve was installed, perhaps like this:
source:www.drainstrain.com
Then you need something to temporarily close the larger opening leading to the bowl, like this:
source:www.essentialvalues.us/products
Then you can take your time pouring about two gallons of water into the tank. Remove the stopper from the larger opening to flush the bowl.
